# Use HTML Form Image to Perform Inference with ONNX.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, machine-learning, onnx

How can I use the image file provided in an HTML `<form>` for inference in an ONNX.js model?

I have a `<form>` like this:

```
<form action="#" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type="file" id="inputImage" accept="image/jpeg" />
</form>
```

And I'm accessing the image file with JQuery as such:

```
const [file] = $("#inputImage")[0].files;
```

ONNX.js's documentation provides [this code snippet](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wmlba/2471b989f0ddba6de304d8654c9e8e27/raw/0cbe8b01e4876c68ca2862117f922aa9e59021f6/index1.js) for performing inference with an image, but that is using an image on the file system, not in an HTML form.